# How to search for only indesign file osx finder?

Tags: osx-lion

I want list to all the indesign file in my external HD, I tried the finder but I don't see an option to search just by extension. I selected the external HD and under kind I selected other that gave me an input box. It works when I type photoshop but doesn't work when I type indesign??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search just for extensions.

Open finder, click on your external HD on the left and search for your file extension in the search input box (i.e. .psd, .pdf, .indd).